# Importing data to Sqlite3

Tags: ios, sqlite

We are using SQLite for our iPad project. We are importing the data from another SQLite. After importing the data we are not able to insert data back into the Sqlite from viewcontroller. 
Throwing an error when we try to access the same in device, while the same works fine in Simulator.

> Error from Device:
>    *** Assertion failure in -[DataBaseSharedManager insertLoginDetails:], /Users/vidya/Desktop/eDetail_feb27/eDetail/Classs/Database files/DataBaseSharedManager.m:165
>   Feb 27 18:07:17 unknown eDetail[1866] :**  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error:failed to save priority with message 'database disk image is malformed''
>   ** First throw call stack:
>       (0x33e758bf 0x352901e5 0x33e757b9 0x3289f3b3 0x336b15 0xae887 0x33dd422b 0x32fd8b 0x328fcc39 0x328546e9 0x328546b3 0x328545d5 0x375048a5 0x374f9545 0x374f9639 0x374f9243 0x374f9179 0x33e49b03 0x33e492cf 0x33e48075 0x33dcb4dd 0x33dcb3a5 0x306b6fcd 0x32393743 0xab125 0xab0bc)

Note: Our SQlite file is 36MB.

Code for reference:

```
NSArray *paths                  = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory    = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath        = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"eTest.sqlite"];


    if (sqlite3_open([writableDBPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK){

        NSString *sSqlSelect = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Insert into LOGIN (LoginId, UserName, Password, LastSyncDate, SFId,SecurityToken, AccountType, SFUserId,Region,ModifiedDate) values (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")", [pDict objectForKey:@"LoginId"],[pDict objectForKey:@"UserName"],[pDict objectForKey:@"Password"],[pDict objectForKey:@"LastSyncDate"],[pDict objectForKey:@"SFId"],[pDict objectForKey:@"SecurityToken"], [pDict objectForKey:@"AccountType"], [pDict objectForKey:@"SFUserId"],[pDict objectForKey:@"Region"],[pDict objectForKey:@"ModifiedDate"]]; 

        sqlite3_stmt *insertValue;
        int nResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sSqlSelect UTF8String],-1,&insertValue,NULL);
        if(nResult == SQLITE_OK){
            sqlite3_step(insertValue);
        }else{
            NSAssert1(0,@"Error:failed to save priority with message '%s'",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(insertValue);
    }else{
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to open database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
```

For transaction: We are exporting the data from one SQLite and importing the same table into another SQLite. We are using the Firefox SQLite Manager for this.

Comment: Please help us in Finding the solution of above question..

Comment: Can u tell which line it is getting exception?

Comment: NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to open database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

Comment: Where are the importing code from one database to another

Comment: We are importing the code manually using the Firefox - Sqlite Database Manager AddOn

Comment: have a look at [this](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html#how_to_corrupt)

Comment: and [this](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DatabaseCorruption)

Answer (score 0):

I think when you are importing the database using firefox it's getting corrupted.

I think you can do the thing by coding read data from one sqlite file and store it another sqlite file.You can just make a short code separately for it and after that just copy and paste the sqlite file in main bundle.

Comment: Yes... is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Created ipa and ran on the actual device and it works fine. When I try to run the application connecting to machine it crashes. –